# Read and decode BLOB image in database, but the image is in application/Octetstream

Tags: image, base64, blob, decoding

I have an image stored in database, with BLOB as datatype but it shows
this content.

[image]

Its also base64 encoded. How to decode this in Java? I have tries several things. but no luck.

Comment: That does not look like [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: Yes that's the issue. It is base64 encoded, but may be encoded with other technique also.Any guess what could it be?